# How Do I navigate using Waze using a voice assistant app (Google Now/AI Assistant)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-galaxy-s-5, google-now

Samsung S5, fully up to date. All defaults have been cleared for Google Search, Waze, and Google Maps.

However if you speak "Ok Google", "Take me home" then tap to navigate, it will ONLY open Google Maps, and will not ask to use another navigation app. Same for AI Assistant.

Tested on Samsung Galaxy S5 & S6